# JAVA JFR call-stack sampling

Tags: java, profiling, jfr

How could one use JFR to sample the call stack programmatically?

Currently, I'm able to print "events" that occur, but it seems I have to define these myself. I have no idea how to sample the call stack, say, every 10ms, to find most called methods in a Java program.

Does using a periodic event to find the stack trace work?

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the tour, if you have not done so already. Also take a look at minimal reproducible example. You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

To sample Java threads that are executing Java code, use the built-in "jdk.ExecutionSample" event. To sample Java threads that are in native (executing or sleeping), use "jdk.NativeMethodSample ".